# How to get url_for working with a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have mounted FullcalendarEngine in my routes.rb:

```
mount FullcalendarEngine::Engine , at: "/fullcalendar_engine"
```

Unfortunately, even though I have this in routes.rb:

```
resources :events,  module: 'fullcalendar_engine'
```

And the generated routes:

```
fullcalendar_engine_path                    /fullcalendar_engine        FullcalendarEngine::Engine
events_path                     GET         /events/index(.:format)     fullcalendar_engine/events#index
event_path                      GET         /events/:id(.:format)       fullcalendar_engine/events#show
events_path                     GET         /events(.:format)           fullcalendar_engine/events#index
                                POST        /events(.:format)           fullcalendar_engine/events#create
new_event_path                  GET         /events/new(.:format)       fullcalendar_engine/events#new
edit_event_path                 GET         /events/:id/edit(.:format)  fullcalendar_engine/events#edit
event_path                      GET         /events/:id(.:format)       fullcalendar_engine/events#show
                                PATCH       /events/:id(.:format)       fullcalendar_engine/events#update
                                PUT         /events/:id(.:format)       fullcalendar_engine/events#update
                                DELETE      /events/:id(.:format)       fullcalendar_engine/events#destroy
```

I still cannot use `url_for` with it (which I need to do in order to get it working with `will_paginate`):

**Error:**

```
RailsDevise::Application.routes.url_for({ controller: 'events', action: 'index'})
=> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"events"}
FullcalendarEngine::Engine.routes.url_for({ controller: 'events', action: 'index'})
=> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"events"}
```

When I inspect the module's routes:

```
FullcalendarEngine::Engine.routes.routes.collect {|journey| journey.defaults }
 => [{:controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events", :action=>"index"}, {:action=>"get_events", :controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events"}, {:action=>"move", :controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events"}, {:action=>"resize", :controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events"}, {:action=>"index", :controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events"}, {:action=>"create", :controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events"}, {:action=>"new", :controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events"}, {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events"}, {:action=>"show", :controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events"}, {:action=>"update", :controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events"}, {:action=>"update", :controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events"}, {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events"}]
```

Notice it has this:

```
@defaults={:controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events", :action=>"index"}
```

Notice the namespace for the controller value. This does not work:

```
FullcalendarEngine::Engine.routes.url_for({:controller=>"events", :action=>"index"})
=> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"events"}
```

But if I try to namespace it, it gives this error:

```
FullcalendarEngine::Engine.routes.url_for({:controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events", :action=>"index"})
ArgumentError: Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

Even adding a host generates the wrong url:

```
FullcalendarEngine::Engine.routes.url_for({:controller=>"fullcalendar_engine/events", :action=>"index", host: "localhost"})
 => "http://localhost/fullcalendar_engine/"
```

How can I get `url_for` to recognize the route?

Answer (score 0):

Your routes expect an `id` parameter, so you need to give it one:

```
url_for(controller: 'events', action: 'show', id: 5)   # < Notice the `id`
```

Additionally, the routes you posted do not include a route for the `index`, so it may not exist. If it did, it probably wouldn't require an `id`

Comment: Actually I did not originally post all the routes. There is indeed an index route. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that encounters this.  I stepped through the Rails code and this is what fixed it for me:

```
FullcalendarEngine::Engine.routes.url_for({:action=>"index", host: "localhost"}, 'fullcalendar_engine_path')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that a question asked 5 years ago may still be pretty relevant. I'm hoping that you have already found a solution. :)

I have been hit by similar problem in **Rails 6.0.3** *(a little old, isn't it?)*, where the `url_for` was exploding in a very similar manner for a controller from a non-isolated engine, inheriting from `::ApplicationController`

I stumbled upon this chain of issues and comments:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37927#issuecomment-695934757
- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40263
- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40264 *(closed as stale)*
- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41463 *(merged, backported to Rails 6.1)*

Long story short, this ugly hack may save your hide **for a while, until you upgrade** to newer Rails:

```rb
class Foo::BarController < ::ApplicationController

  # your normal stuff

  private

  def _routes # <- this overrides an inherited method, so keep the name!
    @_routes || my_engine_routes
  end

  def my_engine_routes # <- and this you can name as you want
    @_my_engine_routes ||= Foo::Engine.routes
  end
end
```

Just be sure to carefully test whether it works well for your case, and do not forget to remove it once you upgrade. It may cause nasty conflicts with some deep magic in Rails!